# Subscribing to Keyframe Selections

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes, graph-editor

I'm using the following to execute a function when the Scene's Active Object has changed. Is it possible to execute a function when the Scene's selected keyframes change (across any objects)? Thank you!

```py
import bpy
        
def msgbus_callback(*arg):
    # in console will be print selected_objects 
    print(bpy.context.selected_objects)
    # you can do something
        
def subscribe_to_obj(): 
             
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=(bpy.types.LayerObjects, 'active'),
        owner=bpy,
        args=('something, if you need',),
        notify=msgbus_callback
        )
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    subscribe_to_obj()
```